# how can i do metabox

Tags: metabox

[image]

how can I make a metabox like in the picture

episode title : Episodes 1

Serie Name : The Seven Deadly Sins

AirDate : gg.aa.yyyy

Comment: Welcome - there are lots of ways to add and control post meta data - using code or using plugins - please take the time to give more information about your questions, aim and current set-up.

Comment: how can I do with code with functions.php

Comment: As I mentioned, please take the time to update your question to show more information, so that others can help you more easily - show the code you have and have tried, show errors you face etc.

Comment: I have no code information how can I make a new one

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'your_callback_function')` https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

Answer (score -1):

ID;
    $meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'episodes', true);
?>

```
<label for="episodes">Bölüm Sayısı Örnek 1.Bölüm:</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="episodes" value="<?php echo $meta_value; ?>" id="episodes" />
</div>
```

ID;

    if (isset($_POST['episodes']) && !empty($_POST['episodes'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'episodes', $_POST['episodes']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'episodes');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'bolumler_save');


See my teacher, I created one but I can use only one of them. Room episodes. I want to add 2 more places. How can I add twshows - into places like seasons?